# How to show data in java fx 8 table view existing between two timestamps

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, timestamp, tableview

I have a question that I couldn't find a solution for.

I'm trying to filter my javafx8 tableview but i'm facing a problem .
I don't know how to show only data existing between two time stamps.

Edit : to be explicit i want to know how to configure a beginnig and an ending for the rows using text field

PS : screenshot of my tableview : 
[image: my table view in javafx8]

I have already seen https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/. I have a trouble with creating a proper `Predicate`, in the tuto they show you how to display only informations that have the same informations. and i want to display the infos existing in between.

PS: item type is Timestamp

Comment: https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/ might help

Comment: thankyou for your help but i've already seen it, i couldn't use it for my wanted task

Comment: Why not? Touble creating a proper `Predicate`? BTW: details about the item type would be helpful. We don't need the whole thing, but the property containing the `LocalDateTime` (or equivalent) would be helpful.

Comment: yes i have a trouble with creating a proper Predicate, in the tuto they show you how to display only informations that have the same informations. and i want to display the infos existing in between, PS: item type is  Timestamp

Comment: Thank you for supplying more information, it’s always welcome. And always best done in the question itself. This time I put it there for you. In the future please edit your question when you have something to add.

Comment: The [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class is `Comparable` and also provides convenience methods to test if one is before, equal to, or after another. Since Java 8 it also has methods to convert it into `java.time` classes—specifically, `LocalDateTime` and `Instant`. These `java.time` classes are also `Comparable` and provide similar convenience methods. When using a `FilteredList`, you need to create a `Predicate` to test if the item's `Timestamp` is between two others (after the start but before the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
confirmdatebtn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                   @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        filterData.setPredicate(table -> {
                            if ((todatetxt.getText() == null &&fromdatetxt.getText() == null) ||
                                    (todatetxt.getText().isEmpty()&&fromdatetxt.getText().isEmpty()) ) {
                                return true;}
                try {
                        String fromtext = fromdatetxt.getText();
                        String totext = todatetxt.getText();
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
                        Date date1 = null;
                        Date date2 = null;
                        Timestamp timestamp1 = null;
                        Timestamp timestamp2 = null;

                        if(todatetxt.getText().isEmpty() && !fromdatetxt.getText().isEmpty()) {
                                date1 = format.parse(fromtext+" 00:00:00.000");
                                timestamp1 = new java.sql.Timestamp(date1.getTime());
                                if (table.getTime_of_action().after(timestamp1) ) 
                                {return true;}
                        }
                        if(!todatetxt.getText().isEmpty() && fromdatetxt.getText().isEmpty()) {
                            date2 = format.parse(totext+" 23:59:59.000");
                            timestamp2 = new java.sql.Timestamp(date2.getTime());
                            if (table.getTime_of_action().before(timestamp2) ) 
                            {return true;}
                        }
                        if(!todatetxt.getText().isEmpty()  && !fromdatetxt.getText().isEmpty()) {
                            date1 = format.parse(fromtext+" 00:00:00.000");
                            date2 = format.parse(totext+" 23:59:59.999");

                            timestamp1 = new java.sql.Timestamp(date1.getTime());
                            timestamp2 = new java.sql.Timestamp(date2.getTime());

                            if (table.getTime_of_action().before(timestamp2) &&table.getTime_of_action().after(timestamp1)) 
                            {return true;}
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e1) {

                    }

                        return false; 
            });} });*** i wrote this code and it came out good so my probleme is resolved thanks to your help guys***
```